# Managed C++ namespace not accesible in C#.Net during compilation

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, managed-c++

I have 4 projects in my Visual Studio 2010 solution. One of the project is managed C++ dll. I have added the project reference of this managed C++ project into remaining three C#.Net projects. When I tried to compile this I got the error at Using namespace statement in C# code.

Managed C++ Code

```
namespace A <---- Defined in managed C++ as well as C#
{
    namespace B <---- Only defined in managed C++
    {
        public ref class MyClass
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I want to use MyClass in my C# so
C#. Net code

```
using A.B;  <-------- Here it gave error for B;
```

The outer namespace i.e. A is defined/used in C# as well as managed C++ project. But the inner namespace i.e. B is defined solely in managed C++. I am not able to access inner namespace in C# application.

Any solution?

Thanks,
Omky

Comment: Have you tried to add your C++ project to C# Project Dependencies and rebuild?

Comment: Maybe it's worth to reflect managed C++ dll and ensure that it really contains A.B.MyClass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes....I found it. I learnt that I need to be sure about the build configuration and output path.Means If I want to build release then have reference to release configuration for all dependent binaries and same for debug too.

Sorry.... I understood my mistake. Thanks to all for your help.

Comment: Please, explain it deeper. As I'm building everything in the same *Release x64* configuration, referenced the project as a dependency, but still not finds the namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Would the [global "::" operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htccxtad%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) help?

Comment: Is it an option/solution to other/different namespace names in either the C++ and/or the C# project?

Answer (score 1):

Always a Big Mistake to ask a question about an error without quoting the *exact* error message.  But the one you'd typically see has this phrase in it:

> Are you missing an assembly reference?